# Create interface for functional component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using react js and typescript.
I have troubles with the next situation:
How to rewrite an interface for the next statement:

```js
export const useHook: () => { isLoaded: boolean } = () => { ... }
```

How you can see, typescript added: `() => { isLoaded: boolean }`. but i don't like this and i want to change with interface. How to write an interface for the code above?

Comment: type HookType = () => { isLoaded: boolean };
export const useHook: HookType = () => { ... }

Does this help?

Comment: `() => { isLoaded: boolean }` is not what typescript added, it is what you wrote in your code. So you want a different type for your function? Also, your snippet does not work.

Comment: And why do you mention functional components in your title? You don't use them in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can change : `{ isLoaded: boolean }` to be an interface:

```
interface test {
    isLoaded: boolean
}

const useHook: () => test = () => { return {isLoaded: true} }
```

If you want to have an interface that contains the useHook function itself, you can also do the following:

```
interface test {
    isLoaded: boolean
}

const useHook: () => test = () => { return {isLoaded: true} }

interface myInterface{
    useHook: typeof useHook
}

export const obj : myInterface = {useHook}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply define interface and pass it as a type.

```
interface LoadState {
    isLoaded: Boolean,
}

export const useHook: (): LoadState => ({ isLoaded: true })
```